# Read database from vm1 to vm2 (ubuntu)?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, database, sql

I have ubuntu on vmware. I've installed mysql-server on it. And now I'd like to connect to this db directly from another ubuntu(2) on vmware. I've set the network adapter to host-only for both vm. I have a php system on vm1 and want to read database from vm2. How do I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using, as this will help in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: While this is possible, I think you are unnecessarily complicating your architecture. You could use a single VM, or even replace the first VM with a container if that is possible.